# $H \trianglelefteq K$, $K/H$ abelian, $N \trianglelefteq G$, then $KN/HN$ abelian

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and $H$, $K$, $N$, subgroups of $G$. $H$ is normal in $K$, $K/H$ is abelian, and $N$ is normal in $G$.

I can show that $HN$ is normal in $KN$, but how to see that $KN/HN$ is abelian if $K/H$ is abelian?

Comment: *Hint*: Write down the obvious homomorphism $K/H\to KN/HN$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it may look like overkill, I believe it is advisable to split the problem in its *elementary* components.

First use the second isomorphism theorem:
$$
\frac{K N}{H N}
=
\frac{K H N}{H N}
\cong
\frac{K}{K \cap H N},
$$
then Dedekind's identity (this step is unnecessary, see the comment beloew):
$$
\frac{K}{K \cap H N}
=
\frac{K}{H (K \cap N)},
$$
and finally the third isomorphism theorem:
$$
\frac{K}{H (K \cap N)}
\cong
\frac{\dfrac{K}{H}}{\dfrac{H (K \cap N)}{H}}
$$
to show that $K N/H N$ is isomorphic to a quotient group of $K / H$. The argument in the other answer then applies.

Comment: Is it necessary to use dedekind's identity (it's my first time seeing it)? Since $H$ is normal in $K$, $H \subseteq HN$, then $H \leq K \cap HN \leq K$, and $H \trianglelefteq K \cap HN$, so we can apply the third isomorphism theorem from there to get $K/(K \cap HN) \cong (K/H)/((K \cap HN)/H)$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Raekye, you are perfectly right, it is unnecessary. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Use the hint in the comments to get a surjective homomorphism, and the fact that the homomorphic image of an abelian group is abelian:    $ab=\phi(g)\phi(h)=\phi(gh)=\phi(hg)=\phi(h)\phi(g)=ba\,,\forall a,b$, where $\phi(g)=a$ and $\phi(h)=b$.

Comment: The "obvious" homomorphism is the projection given by $k + H \in K/H \mapsto k + HN \in KN/HN$. My understanding is this is well defined because $H \leq HN$? Because different elements of the coset $k + H$ all map to the same $k + HN$. But it's not clear to me why this is surjective; given $kn + HN \in KN/HN$, what maps to it?

Comment: $kn_1$ and $kn_2$ differ by an element of $N$ by normality of $N$ in $G$.  Hence they differ by an element of $HN$.  Hence they give the same coset.  So we send $k+H$ to that coset.

Comment: Is it true that $kn + HN = k + HN$ because $n \in HN$? (Sorry for the inconsistent coset notation, have recently been working with rings so I was thinking of cosets with the addition notation). Edit: posted comment at the same time... thinking about yours

Comment: Even better,  I think.  Normality seems to be unnecessary here, on second thought.